# What does caller/sender see when I use call+SMS filter to block him?

Tags: call-sms-filter

When I block certain number, what happens when that person tries to send me sms or call me? What does that other person see? Do they know I blocked them or how is this handled? Thank you

Comment: As far as the sender is concerned, it has been sent, and as for calls, I assume it just drops the call automatically if they try calling.

Answer (score 2):

The blocked person here will see a "Line Busy" status while he calls you. For SMS, he will also get delivered messages like normal cases. These will be no indication that you have blocked him what so ever. On your side, if you go to settings >> call+SMS filter, you can find the blocked calls ans SMS.

Actually here the phone OS receives both the blocked calls and SMS, but lets you have peace by not notifying you for the blocked numbers, that's all.

Comment: Worth noting that they might still get put through to voicemail.